# How do I construct a string consisting of doubles and " " and then give it as const char* to a cMessage constructor?

Tags: c++, omnet++

I'm working on a simulation in OMNet++. I want to send multiple double values in on message, that would look like this: "0.005044 0.345209 0.032458"

For this, I generate 3 double values and then cast them into a stringstream. Then I convert this string stream into a string via str() and this string into a const char*:

```
const char* Provider::getSensor() {
double multibeam, dopVelLog, SubBotPro;

multibeam = uniform(0.0,1.0);
dopVelLog = uniform(0.0,1.0);
SubBotPro = uniform(0.0,1.0);

std::stringstream ss;
ss << multibeam << " " << dopVelLog << " " << SubBotPro;

return ss.str().c_str();
```

}

This seems to work well until you actually do it. I sprinkled some temporary values in there so I could see in the debugger, what str() and c_str() return and I actually got what I wanted (looks exactly like the example above).
BUT: when I tell the program to take the next step (at return), it puts the execution pointer back up to `std::stringstream ss;`, butchers whatever was in there before, jumps right over `ss << multibeam << " " << dopVelLog << " " << SubBotPro;` and then returns a newly formed string ("\0"), because of dark c++-magic. Please, wizards, help me.

Comment: Have `getSensor` return a `std::string`, not a `char*`. You are returning a pointer to a buffer managed by a temporary `std::string`. That string is destroyed when the function returns, leaving the caller with a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
return ss.str().c_str();
```

you are constructing a `const char *` from a `string` that will die when you return from the function. This leaves a dangling pointer at the call site.

Instead, you can return a `string` from the function:

```
std::string Provider::getSensor() {
  // ...
  return ss.str();
}
```

and then you can call `c_str()` on the returned string at the call site, and use the `const char *` obtained there.